# How to SEO pages with adaptively loaded alternative language on same URL?

Tags: seo, internationalization, language, hreflang, dynamic

So, when each page has content on it's own language we use HREFLANG attributes and it's all fine.

But now, if I build a page in English but if user picks to display it in another language, I won't open a new URL of the alternative page in that language, but rather dynamically re-render the page with contents in requested language. URL won't change, contents will. And later, if that user returns to the site, i'll automatically display site contents in his language...

How do I SEO such pages?

I know that I'll need to use vary accept-language, but what else?

Also, if I had to redirect from old Hreglang versions of URLs to this one-of-all URL, would I just 301 redirect those pages to it and auomatically display preset language content according to origins of redirect?

Answer (score 1):

If the page is using query strings to define the content, you can tell Google that this defines a 'new page' even if the URI is identical.

You'll find this under Search Console. Go to Crawl -> URL Parameters and edit the various query strings Google has picked up.

If you don't have a query string or a unique URI then what you're doing could be considered cloaking. This is against Google's best practices - there's no way for them to index your content in a way that it appears consistently for users.